# How to use a mutex in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6, mutex

I have imported the `kernel32` library. So, I have the `createMutex` function available but I am not quite sure of the various parameters and return values.

This is classic Visual Basic, not Visual Basic.NET but I can probably work with either language in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The VB code looks something like this:

```
hMutex = CreateMutex(ByVal 0&, 1, ByVal 0&)
```

The first parameter is a pointer to an `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure. If you don't know what it is, you don't need it. Pass NULL (0).

The second parameter is `TRUE` (non-zero, or 1) if the calling thread should take ownership of the mutex. `FALSE` otherwise.

The third parameter is the mutex name and may be NULL (0), as shown. If you need a named mutex, pass the name (anything unique) in. Not sure whether the `VB` wrapper marshals the length-prefixed `VB` string type (`BSTR`) over to a null-terminated Ascii/Unicode string if not, you'll need to do that and numerous examples are out there.

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

Here's the VB6 declarations for [CreateMutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(VS.85).aspx) - I just copied them from the API viewer, which you should have as part of your VB6 installation. VB6 marshalls strings to null-terminated ANSI using the current code page.

```
Public Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
   nLength As Long
   lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
   bInheritHandle As Long 
End Type

Public Declare Function CreateMutex Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateMutexA" _
   (lpMutexAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal bInitialOwner As Long, _
    ByVal lpName As String) As Long
```

Bear in mind that if you create a mutex from the VB6 IDE, the mutex belongs to the IDE and won't be destroyed when you stop running your program - only when you close the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682411(VS.85).aspx) it looks like:

1. Security attributes (can pass null)
2. Whether it's initially owned (can pass false)
3. The name of it

HTH