# Does VB6 support jumplists

Tags: vb6

Is it possible to modify the jumplist for an exe using VB6? I want to remove the option to launch the exe from jumplist. For example considering chrome is my exe I want to remove the option to launch chrome from the jumplist(highlighted in red). If I could disable jumplist using code(VB6) that would also be fine. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: You can not modify that part of the jump list at all. That entry is purely the "launch this application" which makes no sense to remove. VB6 does however have the same access as any other Win32 application over its own jump list.

Comment: Which jumplist do you want the exe to be removed from? ... the jumplist in your picture is from the taskbar when you hold your mouse down on the chrome icon, but i guess that is not the jumplist you want to work on?

Comment: Okay, so what I get is, there is no way to either disable or hide that option. @Deanna So is there an option to open the same instance of the exe (by right clicking and choosing the first option of launching the exe) that is currently running rather than creating a new instance of the same. Just like how it works when a user left clicks on the exe?

Comment: There are [plenty of ways](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11669643/588306) to switch to an existing instance if one is already open. This also handles the user running it manually, from the start menu, other shortcuts, middle click the button, ctrl+click the button, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name to which you are referring is there to tell a user what program he/she is running, and to provide the user with additional options for a program. Left-clicking on it will open a new instance of the same program. Right-clicking on it will show the additional options. This is the default behaviour of Windows Explorer in Windows 7 and 8 with any program running in the foreground. The name on the context menu of each program running in the foreground, cannot be removed.